# Проблема с инвертированным .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Я пытаюсь настроить файл .gitignore таким образом, чтобы он игнорировал все файлы во всех поддиректориях репозитория, кроме *.c, *.py и .pdf (также во всех поддиректориях). Но проблема в том, что если я составляю .gitignore моего репозитория таким образом:

```
/**/
!/**/*.pdf
!/**/*.с
!/**/*.py
```

То Git все равно игнорирует *вообще все файлы*, не обращая внимания ни на какие из них. В чем моя ошибка и как правильно составить .giignore для моей задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получился такой файл. Подходит?

```
# Игнорируем всё
*
# Но позволяем рекурсивно заходить в папки
!*/
# а также следим за следующими файлами
!*.c
!*.py
!*.pdf
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не подумал про "!*/". Теперь все работает.